# Limiting choice to one

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is for an autocomplete box on our site, and we want to limit the number of selections the user makes to 1. Only one choice would be allowed.

```
// Downloads
$('input[name=\'download\']').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/vdi_download1/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['name'],
                        value: item['download_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(item) {
        $('input[name=\'download\']').val('');

        $('#product-download' + item['value']).remove();

        $('#product-download').append('<div id="product-download' + item['value'] + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>&nbsp; ' + item['label'] + '<input type="hidden" name="product_download[]" value="' + item['value'] + '" /></div>');
    }
});

$('#product-download').delegate('.fa-minus-circle', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Why not just return the first item in the `json` array, instead of the whole thing?

Comment: _Only one choice would be allowed_ -- What do you mean by this? Please clarify.

Comment: 31piy - One choice means the user can only select one item from the list. I need the name of the item for the label and the value for the database entry.

Comment: 31piy - One choice means the user can only select one item from the list. If more items are selected, they would see a message like " Please select only one item"

Andy - I need the name of the item for the label and the value for the database entry.